# iPad 1 unable to record MPEG4AAC recording?

Tags: ipad, ios5, xcode4.2, avaudiorecorder, ios5.1

I have been trying to record kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC format on iPad app, the recording is working fine on iPad2 & iPad3, but not on iPad1. Here iPad1 & iPad3 have iOS 5.1, and iPad2 has iOS 5.0.1.

The code for recording is like..

```
if(recordEncoding == ENC_PCM)
{
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatLinearPCM] forKey: AVFormatIDKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey: AVSampleRateKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:16] forKey:AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey];   
}
else
{
    NSNumber *formatObject;

    switch (recordEncoding) {
        case (ENC_AAC): 
            formatObject = [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC];
            break;
        case (ENC_ALAC):
            formatObject = [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleLossless];
            break;
        case (ENC_IMA4):
            formatObject = [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleIMA4];
            break;
        case (ENC_ILBC):
            formatObject = [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatiLBC];
            break;
        case (ENC_ULAW):
            formatObject = [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatULaw];
            break;
        default:
            formatObject = [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleIMA4];
    }

    [recordSettings setObject:formatObject forKey: AVFormatIDKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey: AVSampleRateKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:12800] forKey:AVEncoderBitRateKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:16] forKey:AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityHigh] forKey: AVEncoderAudioQualityKey];
}
```

Can anyone help me with this problem. One this is for sure, MPEG4AAC works on iPAD 1 as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719865/extaudiofilewrite-to-m4a-aac-failing-on-dual-core-devices-ipad-2-iphone-4s) suggests

Comment: What happens? Error messages? Crashes?

Comment: none, the AudioFile is created, though its of oo:oo secs on disc, and size usually 29 KB. This is only for iPad 1. On iPad2 & 3, everythings working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to comment `AVEncoderBitRateKey` line. Also `AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey` is not needed for `AAC`.

Comment: not working still, i tried all the iterations possible.. Commenting AVEncoderBitRateKey, AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey each one once, then both. None worked.